# Is there an operator for appending to a string variable in ASP?

Tags: php, vbscript, operators

What's the ASP equivalent to PHP's `.=` when concatenating strings? I'm referring to asp NOT asp.net.

I meant to specify that I'm in a for-loop. So I want to know the equivalent for `.=` (in php) not standard concatenation.

*Example:*

```
For Each Item In Request.Form
    If (Item = "service") then 
        For x=1 To Request.Form(item).Count
            service = "&service="&Request.Form(Item)(x)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Please post how you would do this in PHP.

Answer (score 9):

In VBScript:

```
Variable = Variable & "something more"
```

In JScript I believe you can use:

```
variable += "something more";
```

Specifically:

```
service = service & "&service=" & Request.Form(Item)(x)
```

assuming you want your result to look something like...

```
&service=blah1&service=blah2&service=blah3
```

Though you may need to URL encode your Request.Form(Item)(x) values because any "&" (and other characters) could really muck up what you are trying to do.  Also be careful when using unsanitized input like this directly from an HTML form, its very dangerous.

Comment: If you concatenate large strings and your application needs to be performance tuned, look at concatenation to be your first area to improve.  A simple VB6 or C++ COM library which emulates the .NET StringBuilder class will greatly improve performance.

Comment: Or simply use Join on an array and avoid the VB6/C++ marlarky

Answer (score -1):

I can't remember for certain, but &= should work in ASP.  I know it works in VB.Net.  Although I can't recall if that worked in asp.  If that doesn't work, the only solution is a = a & b.

Comment: the a = a & b is the best solution. i don't like asp. thanks for the help guys!